# Alterar o regex de forma que múltiplas URLs não sejam válidas

Tags: regex, url

Tudo bem?

Estou usando o seguinte regex para validar URLs e ele supre a minha necessidade quando tenho apenas uma URL:

```
/^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%=~_|]$/
```

Preciso alterar esse regex de forma que, quando tenho múltiplas URLs, a URL não seja válida.

Resultados esperados:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com => **VÁLIDO**
- https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://google.com => **INVÁLIDO**
- https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com => **INVÁLIDO**
- https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com => **INVÁLIDO**

A minha ideia era alterar esse regex de forma a pegar tudo até a segunda ocorrência de https, ftp ou file (sem contar essas strings) se houver. Tentei utilizar algumas soluções que encontrei no stack, mas nenhuma me deu o resultado esperado.

Poderiam me ajudar por favor? =(

Observação: não estou tentando remover URLs duplicadas. Posso ter uma URL diferente, como é o caso do segundo exemplo inválido apresentado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teoricamente ambas URLs são válidas. Se alguém digitar algo como `https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com` provavelmente está muito errado, mas supondo que seja algo muito especifico, então diria que você pode usar o : só quando se tratar da porta `/^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s:]{1,}([:]\d+)?(\/[^\s:]+)?$/`, note que o `[^\s:]` fará desconsiderar espaços e :, enquanto o `([:]\d+)?` irá aceitar o possiveis portas informadas de forma explicita. De qualquer forma recomendo dar uma olhada https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento! Obrigada pelo comentário! Eu já havia lido a documentação que passou (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) e vi que esse tipo de URL é válida, mas foi um requerimento de negócio =(

Comment: Só pra complementar, se eu não estiver enganado tem dois meios de usar o IDN, uma é com "U-label" (Unicode), a outra é com "A-label" (ASCII), aonde não é usado os acentos. O U-label é convertido usando Punycode para A-label, logo a validação não precisaria de `\w`, podem existir muitas variações de URL. Se o objetivo é validar as entradas. Então o que quero dizer é que nem essa regex na sua pergunta e nem a resposta com lookahead são exatamente soluções. Não precisa de uma regex exagerada como essas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A princípio, bastaria pegar a própria expressão e colocar em um [*lookahead negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - ou seja, entre `(?! )`. Não fica nada bonito, nem legível, nem fácil de entender ou manter:

```
/^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/((?!(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%=~_|])[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;])*[-a-zA-Z\d+&@#/%=~_|]$/
                         ^                                                                         ^
```

Acima eu marquei o início e fim do *lookahead*. Basicamente, ele verifica se em algum ponto à frente **não** existe algo que seja uma URL. Se tiver, a regex falha.

Vale lembrar, porém, que tecnicamente `https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://google.com` é uma URL válida. Pode não ser de um site que existe, mas não é inválida, já que o domínio dela é `pt.stackoverflow.comhttps` (não existe o TLD `comhttps`, mas nem por isso é uma URL inválida, pois o formato [aceita TLD's com mais de 3 caracteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)).

Já o `:` logo depois indica a porta, que no caso não foi informada (por exemplo, em vez de `www.abc.com:80` para indicar a porta 80, é como se tivéssemos "esquecido" e colocado `www.abc.com:`). Já as barras separam o pathname (ex: `www.abc.com/pathname`), que no caso é `/google.com`.

---

De qualquer forma, regex não é a melhor forma de validar URL's. A maioria das linguagens possui API's específicas para tal, e é preferível usá-las.

Comment: Oi @hkotsubo! Muito obrigada pela ajuda. ^w^/ O lookahead negativo resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Se você está procurando uma URL que tenha um protocolo, subdomínios, domínio e terminação, sem que consecutivas terminações interfiram no resultado, você pode usar:

```
/^                      # início da string
    (?<protocolo>       # começa o grupo de protocolo
        \w+             # qualquer conjunto de caracteres entre 1 e infinito
        :\/\/           # sufixo do protocolo
    )
    (?<subdominios>     # começa a captura de subdomínios
        (
            [\w\.]+     # qualquer conjunto de letras e pontos
            \.          # e esse conjunto tem que terminar com um ponto
        )?              # o subdomínio pode ser vazio
    )
    \w+\.               # obtém o domínio e termina com um ponto
    (?<terminacao>
        (com|net|org)   # terminação da URL
        (\.br)?         # opcionalmente uma terminação de país
    )
$/gmx                   # (opcional) limita a uma URL por linha
                        # se tiver mais, descarta
```

[Veja funcionando no regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/20IyVk/1).

Dessa forma, os resultados serão:

```
MATCH    : https://pt.stackoverflow.com
NO MATCH : https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com
NO MATCH : https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com
```

Da lista, somente o primeiro resultado terá um match, e seus consecutivos grupos. Caso você queira obter somente a primeira URL, mesmo que ainda tenham outras URLS na linha, pode remover o `$` no final da expressão. Dessa forma, terá:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com
  -> match: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com
  -> match: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

https://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.comhttps://pt.stackoverflow.com
  -> match: https://pt.stackoverflow.com
```

Claro que essa expressão não pega o conteúdo de query ou path da URL. Se quiser isso, terá que elaborar na sua expressão. Não fiz porque não foi mencionado na pergunta.

Basicamente, o que essa expressão faz é pegar um protocolo no começo da string, que sempre é `^(?<protocolo>\w+:\/\/)`, ou seja, qualquer conjunto de caracteres desde que precedido por um `://`. Após isso, opcionalmente ele procura por subdomínios em `(?<subdominios>([\w\.]+\.)?)`, que podem ser compostos ou não, e então ele pega o resto da URL terminando sempre em `.com`, opcionalmente com um `.br` no final.

É importante definir quais terminações você quer que a expressão pegue em `(com|net|org)`, se não ela vai confundir a terminação com o começo da próxima URL.

Comment: Oi @CypherPotato, não tenho pontuação suficiente para marcar a sua resposta como útil, mas agradeço muito pela atenção e explicação completa! ç-ç 

Guardarei para futuras referências. Para este caso específico, precisei usar uma regex mais generalizada e o negative lookahead sugerido pelo hkotsubo me atendeu .